# Postgress Query SQL

Tags: postgresql

Olá.
Apresente o código e descrição do grupo e a quantidade de produtos associados a cada um dos grupos. Ordene o resultado pela quantidade de produtos de cada grupo.
Estou com dificuldade de como fazer essa parte "e a quantidade de produtos associados a cada um dos grupos". Segue a baixo a minha tabela GRUPO e a minha tabela PRODUTO.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As duas primeiras colunas é a minha tabela GRUPO. O restante é a tabela PRODUTO. Estou com a seguinte Query:

select grupo.codgru, grupo.descricao

from grupo, produto

where

order by

Comment: Poderia postar o código SQL de criação das tabelas (CREATE TABLE)? Se puder postar um exemplo de como precisa que os dados sejam retornados facilita bastante para quem for responder sua pergunta.

Comment: Olá amigo. Fiquei sem net..Mas creio que nao tem necessidade de ver o código SQL das duas tabelas, pois devo apenas criar a regra SQL apresentando oq me pede na questão. Eu não estou conseguindo entender como faço para apresentar a quantidade de produtos associados a cada um dos grupos.